# Loop method stops running on an Arduino nano v3 when using Serial.print

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I'm trying to do a very simple serial communication, but the loop method seems to stop after using Serial.print().

What's really weird is everything is working well when I run my code from the IDE with the Serial monitor opened, but stop working after 10s when I plug the board to an usb port.

Here is the code I'm using :

```
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("Tick #");
  delay(1000);
}
```

After 10s or 10 loops ? or 10 Serial.print() ? I notice that the tx led stops blinking.

Any idea what I'm missing here ? or what could by wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm a little confused by "when I plug the board to an usb port." Don't you have to have the board plugged into USB in the first place to see serial monitor output?

Comment: Actually "when I plug the board to an usb port" means when the app runs once it is plugged to a usb port (ex. RPI, PC, TV,...etc.) and not from the IDE i.e. after an upload or after opening the serial monitor.

Comment: how can you tell it not working when it's plugged into a tv?

Comment: Because the onboard Tx led stop flashing. When I plug/start the arduino I can see the led flashing 10 times (every second because of the `delay(1000)` ) and then it stops.